# Maven Webstart Plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse, java-web-start

I'm looking for a possibility to run a project using maven webstart plugin directly in eclipse. I get an error saying:

`Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:`
`org.codehaus.mojo:webstart-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-3-cx:jnlp-download-servlet (execution: default, phase: process-resources)`

Has anyone a solution for that problem or any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The groupId was changed in 1.0-beta-3 from 'org.codehaus.mojo.webstart' to 'org.codehaus.mojo', so you need to remember to change it inside of the org.eclipse.m2e section of the pom as well.

I had the same problem, and I had previously updated the groupId's, but had forgotten to also change it for the plugin used by m2e.  Once I correct the groupId to the new value, the error disappeared.

```
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.codehaus.mojo <-- Was org.codehaus.mojo.webstart until 1.0-beta-3!
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        webstart-maven-plugin
```

Changes info: http://www.mojohaus.org/webstart/webstart-maven-plugin/upgrade.html

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to fill constinously all the pom.xml with the same text which it could be anoying, you can setup this in the eclipse configuration as it is described here:

https://mahichir.wordpress.com/2014/05/14/solving-the-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-error-in-eclipse/

This is a general solution for all the plugins under **Eclipse**, a concrete solution for this *org.codehaus.mojo* plugin was the next for me with the *1.0-beta-6* version instead:

Go to Eclipse **Preferences** => **Maven** => **Lifecycle Mappings** => **Open Workspace lifecycle mappings metadata** and save the next xml code in the file *lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lifecycleMappingMetadata>
    <pluginExecutions>
        <pluginExecution>
            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>webstart-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <versionRange>[1.0-beta-6,)</versionRange>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jnlp-download-servlet</goal>
                </goals>
            </pluginExecutionFilter>
            <action>
                <ignore>true</ignore>
            </action>
        </pluginExecution>
    </pluginExecutions>
</lifecycleMappingMetadata>
```